# Replace the first 2 lines containing a string with a specific line with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to replace the first 2 occurrences of:

```
"<version>*"
```

with

```
"<version>$NEW_VERSION</version>"
```

within an already existing xml file.

Original:

```
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Desired result:

```
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I've tried for a while now and this:

```
sed -i -e '0,/<version>*/s/<version>*/<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT<\/version>/' pom.xml
```

gets close, but the resulting string is:

```
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: You're confusing regexp syntax with globbing patterns. In a globbing pattern `*` means "any characters" while in a regexp (as you're trying to use it) it means "0 or more repetitions of the preceding regexp segment". So in a globbing pattern `>*` means "> followed by any characters" but in a regexp it means "the character `>` repeated zero or more times". They sound similar but are actually very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
$ awk -v new_version="1.3.1-SNAPSHOT" 'BEGIN {matches = 0} /^<version>/ && matches < 2 {print "<version>" new_version "</version>"; matches++; next} 1' pom.xml
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

If you have whitespaces before `<version>` lines like that:

```
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

and you want to save them:

```
$ awk -v new_version="1.3.1-SNAPSHOT" 'BEGIN {matches = 0} /^( *)<version>/ && matches < 2 { match($0, "^ *"); print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) "<version>" new_version "</version>"; matches++; next} 1' pom.xml
<groupId>my.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <version>1.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: works great!
But not when there are spaces/tabs infront of the original <version>.
I didnt include that in the original question, so shame on me i guess.
Any tips on how to detect the <version> with an unknown amount of spaces/tabs infront?

Comment: Do you want to save leading whitespaces in output?

Comment: if possible yes

Comment: works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/<version>/{x;s/^/x/;/xx{2}/!{x;s/(<version>)[^<]*/\1NEW VERSION/;x};x}' file
```

Match `<version>` on any line,swap to the hold space, increment a counter and if that counter exceeds the required number of overall substitutions, continue with no further processing.

Otherwise, swap back to the pattern space and substitute the new version.